# R - getting the information from a saved ML model

Tags: r, r-caret

Let's say that somebody developed a model and saved it in a file called `mymodel.Rdata`. When I run it in the console, it says:

```
eXtreme Gradient Boosting 

300000 samples
    10 predictor
     2 classes: 'NO', 'YES' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 300000, 300000, 300000, 300000, 300000
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  nrounds  Accuracy   Kappa    
   400     0.7541231  0.5132452
   700     0.7432121  0.5032432
  1000     0.7315435  0.4954325

Tuning parameter 'max_depth' was held constant at a value of 86
Tuning parameter 'eta' was held constant at  parameter 'colsample_bytree' was held constant at a value of 0.4
Tuning parameter 'min_child_weight' was held constant at a value of 4
Tuning parameter 'subsample' was held constant at a value of 0.9
Accuracy was used to select the optimal model using the largest value.
The final values used for the model were nrounds = 400, max_depth = 7, eta = 0.2, gamma =
 0, colsample_bytree = 0.6, min_child_weight =  and subsample = 0.8.
```

I don't have idea or the data about how this model was built, and I only have this file. How can I get the maximum information of this model? (features used, names of features, transformations, class of features, an example of the features used, etc) Is there any function? Because `summary()` doesn't say much. The code I used:

```
load("mymodel.Rdata")

model_ # this is what was loaded then I loaded the file mymodel.Rdata
# this output is above

class(model_)
[1] "train"         "train.formula"
```

Comment: you can have more insights by subsetting `model_$trainingData`

Comment: You can use `str` on the `model_` to see it's structure. Extracting useable information may require other methods from the package.

Comment: use `model_$trainingData` to see the data with which it was fit. use `model_$call` to see the code which generates the model. use `model_$finalModel` to see the best model built after the 5-fold corss validation. In general use `$`  to access all the component of the model